# Как сделать кастомный tab bar?

Tags: ios, swift

Кто нибудь подскажите как сделать вот такой tab bar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Незнаю как сделать так чтобы линия обтекала логотип как на рисунке
Пока что получилось только так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо за любую информацию

Comment: Сделать картинку с линией и положить ее под кнопку.

Answer (score 0):

По нормальному такое делается через маску:

1. Делаем `UIBezierPath`, путь для маски
2. Создаем `CAShapeLayer`. в поле `path` ложим созданный путь
3. Ложим слой маски в `view.layer.mask`

Почитайте лучше тут: https://www.appcoda.com/bezier-paths-introduction/